# itext pdf generator is an open source library for android?

Tags: android, pdf, itext

In my project want to read and write the pdf file.

I saw some tutorial using droidtext and itext library.

In some links they mentioned itext is not an opensource library.

In Confused to used itext library or not because it is not an opensource.

Any one clarify this doubt?

Any other library is there?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

iText is still an open source library. See http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/ if you want to take a look at the code. For Android, there is iTextG: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextg/ You can find the source code for iTextG here: http://sourceforge.net/p/itextg/code/HEAD/tree/

You can also find our projects on Github: https://github.com/itext

If you find a place where somebody claims that iText is not open source, please let us know, so that we can ask those people to stop spreading non sense! The fact that I can point you at the source code of iText should be sufficient proof that those people are wrong.

This being said: the fact that iText is open source doesn't mean that the software can be used without having to buy a license. You can use iText for free if you obey the rules of the license: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCwhEWEPV-E

It is very strange: the name "Free Software" was replaced by "Open Source Software" because developers wanted to make it clear that the "Free" in "Free Software" was not a synonym of "Gratis". Now that every one talks about "Open Source Software", many people thing that "Open Source Software" is a synonym of "Gratis Software".

This is explained in detail on the official iText web site: http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq

Note that droidtext is not an official iText product. It is a fork that is not endorsed by the creators of iText based on a version of iText that is not supported (it was declared End-of-Life years ago).